# Django models 'values()' and LEFT OUTER join

Tags: python, django, django-models

Consider the following models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)

class Provider(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

When I perform a query similar to:

```
Product.objects.values('name', 'provider__name', 'customer__name')
```

The generated SQL uses LEFT OUTER join instead of INNER join. While using `filter` uses INNER JOIN. How can I use `values()` and avoid the unnecessary NULL field filtering induces by the LEFT OUTER join?

Why is there a difference in `filter()/values()` functions behavior?

Comment: What if you use Product.objects.all().select_related() ?

Comment: Unfortunately `select_related()` doesn't cover reverse relationships

Answer (score 1):

you can use a filter after the values like this:

```
Product.objects.values('name', 'provider__name', 'customer__name').filter(provider__name__isnull=False)
```

I am not 100%sure but give it a try! and lemme know!

Comment: It does the trick. However the resulting query seems not very efficient. It uses LEFT OUTER JOIN and then filters results using WHERE clause, instead of INNER JOIN. I am aware of that solution but I hope there is a better one. BTW, `provider__name__isnull=False` in my case.